# How can I write " > yes" to txt file by batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How can I write  `> yes` to txt file by batch file
They have examples but they do not work
Example 1: `echo > yes >> example.txt`
Commande ECHO activ.e. Write a error message in the example.txt file
Please help where

Comment: or echo hellow >yes >> example.txt    not work i want write hellow >yes

Comment: the vbs work but batch file not work please help

Comment: duplicate: [How can I add greater than and less than into a batch file variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43349134/995714)

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `>` character. Otherwise it gets interpreted as a redirection operator. Escape it with the `^` character. This works:

```
echo ^> yes >> example.txt
```

See [this page](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) for more information about escaping special characters.

Comment: @idirbenyahia Please see [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) Accepting an answer is the best way to say "thanks, it works".